# How to pass a key, certificate, ca and

Tags: node.js, https, node-red, self-signed

I am working with self signed certificates for the fist time. I understand that node red does not use the default ca store. The solution to this seems to be to provide a key and self signed certificate when preforming an https request. I would like to uses the standard http request node to do this but i cant find documentation on how to a key, cert, and rejectUnauthorized through the message block. Is this even possible?

Thank you

Comment: Please show some part of your code to better understand the context of your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NodeJS bundles the default CA store into the node binary so you can't just add a file to a dir and have it pick up extra CA certs.

Assuming you are using the HTTP-request node you can add certs/keys by ticking the "Enable secure (SSL/TLS) connection" check box.

[image]

This should make a drop down box appear that will let you create a new TLS configuration. In here you can add the certs and keys for the connection.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I forgot to say that I am stuck on 0.11 and cant use that method. Is there any other way? Thanks again

Comment: 0.11 is very old you should upgrade as soon as possible. No there is no other way. The only thing you could do is turn off ALL certificate checking but this is not a good idea